# Disabling Geoman edit mode for certain layers in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

Cross post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77166254/disabling-leaflet-geoman-for-certian-layers-doesnt-work). I use [leaflet geoman](https://geoman.io/) for editing lines and [leaflet-arrowheads](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-arrowheads) for rendering lines direction. I am looking for a way to disable leaflet geoman edit mode for layers generated by arrowheads, but for some reason `allowEditing` option doesn't work.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5c4wfsj/)

```
L.PM.Utils.findLayers(map).forEach((layer) => {
   if (layer?._arrowheads){
    const arrows = layer.getArrowheads()
        console.log({arrows})
    arrows?.pm.setOptions({ allowEditing: false })
        arrows?.eachLayer(arrowLayer => {
           console.log({arrowLayer})
           arrowLayer?.pm.setOptions({ allowEditing: false })
        })
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: There are no arrow heads in your JSFiddle code. Please add relevant code to JSfiddle example.

Comment: @TomazicM sorry wrong jsfiddle. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that somehow map pan/zoom destroys `allowEditing: false`. If you try to edit line with arrow immediately after enabling edit, without map pan/zoom first, you'll notice that arrow editing is disabled. But as soon you pan or zoom map or even edit line node with arrow, editing is enabled on the arrow.

One possible solution is to remove the arrows from the lines at the start of the edit and then add arrows when edit is finished.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this (tested):

```
map.on('pm:globaleditmodetoggled', (evt) => {
  L.PM.Utils.findLayers(map).forEach((layer) => {
    if (layer._arrowheads || layer._hasArrowheads) {
     if (evt.enabled) {
        layer.deleteArrowheads();
        layer._hasArrowheads = true;
        }
      else {
        layer.remove();
        layer.arrowheads(arrowheadsOptions);
        layer.addTo(map);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: this is great suggestion. Thank you!